# Maximum Number of Tweets using Selenium 301

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, twitter

So i am trying to extract twitter data using selenium and i have the problem that i cannot extract more then 301 tweets, despite more should be loaded. Here is my code:

```
# logs into twitter and extracts the site /hashtag/Food
driver = twitter_login("Food")
time.sleep(3)

counter = 0
last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
while counter < 100:
    print(counter)
    page = driver.page_source
    # get the data i want
    temp = extract_data(page)
    # store data in dataframe
    if counter > 0:
        data = pd.concat([data, temp])
    else:
        data = temp
    print(temp)    

    # scroll down
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")

    # Wait for the page to load:
    time.sleep(5)

    # Calculate new scroll height:
    new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
    print(f"last hight:{last_height}, new hight: {new_height}")
    if new_height == last_height:
        break
    last_height = new_height
    counter += 1

driver.close()
```

The twitter_login function is does not cause any issues. All it does is just log in to the website. The extract_data function does just that. I have set a counter to test the program, however it just stops where the total number of tweets has reached 301. No error nothing. So obviously the reason must be that at that point: new_height == last_height. However, for example i ran a test today and got for the hashtag Food results only from the current day, which obviously implies that not all tweets will be loaded. Is anybody facing similar issued? How is there a workaround? My guess is that twitter is preventing indefinite scrolling by doing that.